# How to loop over a list of dict elements in Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I have the following variables in my var file:

```
aws:
  profiles:
    - name: default
      properties:
        aws_access_key_id: changeme
        aws_secret_access_key: changeme
        region: eu-west-1
        format: json
    - name: playground
      properties:
        aws_access_key_id: changeme
        aws_secret_access_key: changeme
        region: eu-west-1
        format: json
```

I want to configure each aws profile (`aws.profiles.name` property) with the `properties` field, where the `properties` is a dict, meaning that I want the key and value to be set for each aws profile.

I have tried several approaches, including `with_items`, `with_dict` and `with_nested` but nothing helped. The most logical case looks like this:

```
- name: Configure accounts.
  shell: aws configure set {{ item.properties.key }} {{ item.properties.value }} --profile {{ item.name }}
  with_dict: "{{ aws.profiles }}"
```

But it throws an error:

> "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error
>   was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'properties'

Another approach doesn't work as well, but this time at least `properties` were recognized:

```
- name: Configure accounts.
  shell: aws configure set {{ item.properties.key }} {{ item.properties.value }} --profile {{ item.name }}
  with_items: "{{ aws.profiles }}"
```

The error this time was:

> The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was:
>   'dict object' has no attribute 'key'

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Refactor `properties` to be a list of dicts and use `with_subelements`.

Comment: Thanks, this helped! I posted the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I tried to follow the way suggested by **@Konstantin Suvorov** and it worked.

Refactored variables now looks like this:

```
aws:
  profiles:
    - name: default
      properties:
        - key: aws_access_key_id
          value: changeme
        - key: aws_secret_access_key
          value: changeme
        - key: region
          value: eu-west-1
        - key: format
          value: json
    - name: playground2
      properties:
        - key: aws_access_key_id
          value: changeme
        - key: aws_secret_access_key
          value: changeme
        - key: region
          value: eu-west-1
        - key: format
          value: json
```

The task itself looks like this:

```
- name: Configure accounts.
  shell: "aws configure set {{ item.1.key }} {{ item.1.value }} --profile {{ item.0.name }}"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ aws.profiles }}"
    - properties
```